# I have 3 types of prices in WP and I need to change price for each specific user role using hooks

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, user-roles, meta-value

not a tough coder so could use some help here. What I'm trying to do is, I have 3 types of prices in WP and I need to change price for each specific user role using hooks https://itgalaxy.company/%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-1%D1%81-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82/
This is the plugin page with the docs, so for example I got product_1 with 3 types of prices dealer price, wholesaler price, and retail price, different users get associating roles, so I want WP to show different prices per each role, dealer gets the dealer price as the wholesaler gets the wholesale price and common visitors get retail price.

```
add_action('itglx_wc1c_after_set_product_price', function ($productOrVariationID) {

    $allPriceTypes = \get_option('all_prices_types', []);

    $allProductPrices = \get_post_meta($productOrVariationID, '_all_prices', true);
    
    if($roles[0] == "wholesaler"){
        
    foreach ($allPriceTypes as $guid => $priceType) {
        
        if($priceType['name'] == "Диллерское соглашение"){
            
    update_post_meta(
        $productOrVariationID,
        '_price',
        isset($allProductPrices[$guid]) ? $allProductPrices[$guid] : ''
    );
            
        }}}
});
```

this is what I have already done but that doesnt change nun(((

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't the answer you're looking for - but you're setting yourself up for quite a bit of work.

The Woocommerce Wholesale Suite does exactly what you need flawlessly without all the extra work (aswell as role specific payment methods / shipping methods).

https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-wholesale-prices/

Comment: Thanks for your help bro!

Comment: Thing is these prices are set automatically in DB when I exchange data with 1C. So I need these prices to be set automatically for each user role